# Missing Canon Printer driver for OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, printing, driver, scanning, canon

I hooked up a Canon Pixma MP160 printer/scanner to a machine running OSX Mavericks and it complained that there was no driver.  Scanning through the list of possible drivers, there were only 1 or 2 Canon drivers and none looked close to right.  Canon's website said the driver should be built into OSX.

Is there an MP160 (or compatible) driver for Mavericks?

Comment: what list did you look at?

Comment: Did you try to connect wirelessly or through USB? You might need to hard-wire it to the Mac to have the system see the driver is needed through Software Update. See this KB article for more info: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3669

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to look for what you need, if you are looking for a driver for the Canon Pixma MP160 printer / scanner to a machine running [OSX Mavericks come in here](http://www.thecanondriver.com/search/label/PIXMA%20MP), and if there is no, [please see here](http://www.canon.ca/inetCA/en/serviceDetail?id=5&sid=27&mid=0002200246&type=D), hopefully useful

Comment: Please add the information in your answer instead of referring to websites that may disappear in the future.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to attach a driver to an answer :-)